# SerialPort Encoding

Tags: c++, encoding

I try to configure serial port in C++, every thing goes right except its Encoding.
My code is:

```
serialPort->PortName = "COM3";
serialPort->BaudRate = 115200;
serialPort->NewLine = "***";        
serialPort->Encoding = Encoding->GetEncoding(28591);
```

I get the following error:

```
type name is not allowed.
```

How to use Text Encodings in C++?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE], without which, just by looking at those snippets, it is hard to tell what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `Encoding` is a type name, and the last line in the code snippet must be

```
serialPort->Encoding = Encoding::GetEncoding(28591);
```